Circuit design to prevent the coax cable from becoming the neutral back to the transformer from the house
A 240v line runs to a house from an autotransformer operated by the power company, and a coax cable makes the same run.  At the pole the coax shield is connected to the floating ground of the autotransformer, at the house the coax shield is connected to the neutral/ground of the house.  The shield of the coax is then a second/parallel return path for the neutral. When the power company neutral is cut, the coax then becomes the only low impedance return path for the neutral to the autotransformer.  What circuit design could prevent this from occurring?
The isolation device comparable to the recommended device here in the US is a coax isolation transformer built inside a coax connector.  Specs on it are that it isolates both the inner wire and outer shielding of the coax through the use of a transformer.  If I read this correctly, then would the correct circuit design be to have an isolation transformer on both the coax cable and the main power to the house, essentially putting all the electrical components in the house on an earth ground defined by grounding rods connected to the neutral of the electrical panel (not the grounding rods connected to the meter), with no path back to the transformer or the cable company feed?

Interesting problem and certainly valid for this site, but perhaps a better fit over at DIY? I'm not voting to close however and happy to be in the minority here, just throwing it out as an option.

Curious to know which country.

What signals does the coax transport?

"floating ground" seems like an oxymoron. Are you referring to the Neutral at that point?

This is in the US, the coax carries the internet and a phone line.  I had never heard of a floating ground before, but this was what was described to me that the autotransformer has.  I believe you may be correct that it is the neutral in the autotransformer, and it is bonded to the earth ground there at the pole, but when the neutral is broken, earth ground does not supply a sufficient return to the autotransformer, so the coax, bonded to the transformer, supplies it.

Are you sure it is an "autotransformer" and not just a "transformer"?

In the USA, Comcast will put an "isolator" on the cable to prevent line voltage from getting into their system.  This can occur from home installed surge protectors, when the house wiring isn't correctly done.

The power company told me it is an autotransformer.

"At the pole the coax shield is connected to the floating ground of the autotransformer" this needs clarification. The shield is likely connected to earth ground - not directly the transformer. "the coax shield is connected to the neutral/ground" that doesn't make sense or it's wired wrong and not to code. You cant use the neutral as your shield ground.

Asking about an isolation transformer for you whole house significantly increases the scope of your question. Please do no do that if the question already has answers. Instead, ask a new question. Also, in general, it is better not to pack multiple questions into one post unless the answer to one helps resolve confusion about another, or they are otherwise intrinsically bound together.

MOSFET, electrical code says the neutral is connected to the ground at the house, which is why is used neutral/ground, as they are bonded.  The coax is connected to the transformer ground, not earth ground.   Math Keeps Me Busy, I inserted this as a possible circuit design, as I don't understand how isolating the coax alone with give a complete solution for a circuit design.

@rmcdow24 Yes, the neutral is bonded to ground in the house. And yes, the transformer center-tap (neutral) is bonded to ground on the pole. That part is fine. The problem is that it's implemented wrong if you coax shield is the neutral if the real (intended) neutral is opened. In fact, even if the neutral is perfectly secured, there will likely be interference on the coax - what you are describing is an ideal situation for a ground loop. So, it seems you are asking for a solution to fix poor wiring instead of having the wiring corrected.

@MOSFET.  Thanks for your comments.  The coax shield is connected to the ground of the house at the house end, and the transformer ground (which I was told is floating, whatever that means) at the pole.  The issue that arises because the neutral at the house is bonded to the ground at the house.  None of this is poor wiring according to code.  It is wired correctly, but this wiring does not work when the neutral is broken to the transformer. This is why I am looking for a circuit design that will not have the issues that the code compliant implementation has.

Ok a data coax for CATV or internet (etc) and the supply cable make the same run.
fit a CATV isolator to the coax,

I found this on on ebay australia, but they are on amazon too, but amazon is hiding them from me.
I have not looked inside the one, but the one used on a VHF only live chassis television set had high voltage ceramic capacitors inside. connecting the input terminals to their corresponding output terminals.

Seems like you're answering a "circuit design" question with a "shopping" answer. So while the question has been edited into being on-topic, your answer isn't.

@brhans Shopping questions are off-topic, but are answers that recommend off-the-shelf products verboten?

@JohnD - well it doesn't really answer the question, does it? The request is (now): "What circuit design could prevent this from occurring?", and this "answer" just says: "buy this thing", without making any attempt to detail the circuit design inside the thing.

@brhans Fully agree that the answer could be more informative, I was just wondering if there was some kind of rule against "shopping" answers as well as questions.  If not, we're free to downvote an answer that has substandard content.

How much circuit design can I draw when it takes only a single part? This is a solved problem, there is an inexpensive mass-produced, off-the-shelf, solution. I see no reason to DIY this, If you mess this up you could start a fire. What's inside? It could be HV ceramic capacitors, or could be a transformer,

@Jasen's answer is adequate. However, I want to address the fact that there are two types of cable tv isolators. One is the type shown in @Jasen's answer, which probably contains two high voltage safety capacitors. The second has an internal transformer.
While it is theoretically possible to use an isolator with either topology, it is important that the isolator be rated to withstand the 240 VAC that could theoretically arise in the case of a lost neutral.
A light-weight transformer isolator is almost certainly not designed for 240 V isolation but only for low voltage ground currents.
You MUST check the rated isolation voltage. Unless the transformer is significantly heavier than the cheap transformer coax isolators I see on Amazon, it is very unlikely they are built to withstand 240 VAC. Go with the two capacitor type isolators (assuming they are properly rated).

I don't understand how isolating the coax alone with give a complete solution for a circuit design.

Capacitors "impede" the flow of alternating current. The higher the frequency (up to a point) the less impedance they have. The isolator is designed so that at the frequencies used by cable TV, they have very little impedance, but at mains frequency, their impedance is enough to limit the current to levels that won't cause a fire.
If you want to ask how to protect your house and belongings from a lost neutral, that is an entirely different question than preventing the coax from taking on neutral current. Stopping neutral current from flowing through the coax will NOT protect your house or belongings from a lost neutral. For that, you need some variety of breaker that will break your circuit on over-voltage. But, again, that is a separate question, and is probably better suited for diy/home improvement stack exchange.

Appendix
I am appending some information to my answer to respond to comments by @MOSFET.
Here is an image of the typical wiring of a single phase overhead distribution transformer.

(image uploaded to researchgate.net by Anamika Dubey.)
Note that the neutrals of both the primary side and the secondary side are tied to ground. In reality, this means that these two neutrals are tied to each other, and also to a wire going down the pole and into a short (1 foot typical) grounding rod at the bottom of the pole.
The neutral wire between the substation and a distribution transformer is quite long, and hence has some resistance. Hence there would be a significant voltage difference between the neutral at the substation and the neutral at the distribution transformer, except that there are periodic ties of the neutral to ground. One at each transformer, and if the transformers are too far apart then the code calls for so many per mile.
Because of the resistance of the neutral wire, a portion of the "return" current to the substation returns through the ground. Some of that return current reaches the ground through the grounding system of subscriber circuits. Thus, even with appliances and devices disconnected from a household's electrical system, current will still flow through the household's grounding system.
This video shows an example of someone searching for the source of current flowing through his grounding system, even though his power is off. (He only gets as far as realizing that the current is coming through the neutral wire from the service transformer to his electrical panel).
This paper discusses grounding (in the US) electric power distribution system.
This paper is somewhat of a mixed bag, with some "pop" science, and with a political agenda.  However it discusses the issue of return current to the substation passing through the ground in some detail.

Thanks for your response.  I understand that  stopping the current from flowing through the neutral will just move the problem to the house power legs.  The seller on Amazon responded to my question about the load carrying capacity of his device by saying that with a load of 25 amps the device would melt, as I suspected.  What I have read is that one of the primary causes of electrical house fires is a broken neutral, and that many are caused by a burning coax cable. I will formulate a question that addresses the larger issue and post it separately.

Thank you for this information.  That setup at the power company transformer explains some things, as well as your explanation of the return path.  I have a call scheduled with the power company's engineer this coming week, and will go over my concerns with him.  They are addressing the issues, and hopefully there will be a solution forthcoming.

The problem does not exist. I work for a utility and am here to tell you that your transformer ground is not Floating. Second, it is not an Autotransformer, as that would certainly get people killed and set many buildings on fire. The utility's grounded circuit conductor (aka neutral) is solidly bonded to the earth at the transformer and every other pole all the way back to the substation. The transformer and service equipment ground electrodes are miles and miles of buried copper.
Electrical Codes require the neutral to be bonded to earth at the service entrance before it enters the premises.
If utilities did not ground their equipment, you would have a mountain of dead bodies and ashes piled up. Many folks had to die to learn that. Electrical and building codes ink is made from blood.

The utility company told me that the transformer is an autotransformer.  They also said that it is a floating ground, which I now understand is probably, as you said, the neutral  is bonded to earth at the pole.  No idea why they called it a floating ground, but that transformer ground is what the coax is connected to.  I see the ground wire on the pole, so know that there is an earth ground there.  Current does now flow through the coax shield, as it is a lower impedance connection than between the two earth grounds 300' away from each other.

@rmcdow24 Again, if you have any appreciable current flowing on you coax shield, something is wired wrong. The only current that should be on the shield would be EMI-induced current - the sole purpose of the shield. You have been misinformed by a linesmen/service tech of dubious competence. There is no "floating ground" on the pole. And the transformer is not of the "auto-transformer" variety - that means something substantially different.

@MOSFET while I agree with you regarding the "autotransformer" and the "floating ground", I disagree that current flowing through grounded conductors is abnormal or a sign of a fault. Yes, transformers are grounded at pole, but some current (from the primary side) that is headed back to the substation through the ground also flows through the neutral wire to the house and then to the house's ground. It also flows through copper pipes. This is normal, and acceptable. If both ends of a coax are grounded, it would not be uncommon, especially for a 300 foot run, for current to flow through it.

"...but some current (from the primary side) that is headed back to the substation through the ground also flows through the neutral wire to the house and then to the house's ground." This is just not true. One of the functions of the transformer is to ISOLATE the distribution currents from the house currents. What you described is a failing transformer with poor insulation characteristics. And if you have any appreciable (electrical) current flowing flowing through your copper pipes, you have something wrong. That is not normal.

@MOSFET, to respond to your comment, I needed images and more space than comments allow. So I have added an appendix to my answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/725770/268467
